# Can I use WPF DataTrigger for setting constant value to my DataContext object and TimePicker at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpftoolkit

I have two RadioButtons and a TimePicker control on my screen. For a TimePicker, active_end_Date is a property in DataContext whose value is being set from TimePicker Value Property.
If one of the two RadioButton is Checked, I want to set Value property of TimePicker to 23:59:59 which in turn should update my DataContext value.

```
<RadioButton Content="Occurs at once: " FontSize="18" GroupName="DailyFreqGroup" Name="DailyFreqGroupRadio1"/>
<xctk:TimePicker Name="EndTimeTextBoxDailyFreq"  Value="{Binding Path=active_end_date, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}
    , ConverterParameter='active_end_date'}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" MinWidth="100" Format="LongTime">
    <xctk:TimePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:TimePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="01-01-0001 PM 11:00:00"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=DailyFreqGroupRadio1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="01-01-0001 PM 05:00:00">
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </xctk:TimePicker.Style>
</xctk:TimePicker>
```

I think, I need to assign some sort of Converter but don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the question? Is that solution not working?

Comment: Your `DataTrigger` is replacing the Binding stored in `TimePicker.Value` with a static `DateTime` string. A better solution would be to bind the `IsChecked` property of `DailyFreqGroupRadio`, and whenever that property changes in the ViewModel, update the `active_end_date` property

Comment: @devhedgehog: Yes, this code is not working. I was expecting to see this time in TimePicker, however it is not being set.

Comment: @Rachel: Reverse is happening. Binding is replacing static value set by DataTrigger. I confirmed it by removing Binding from TimePicker.Value

Comment: @ShantanuGupta According to the [Dependency Property Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing), Local values set in XAML overwrite any set via a Style Trigger. If you set the `Value` property to your binding inside a style setter, the trigger would be the last one applied. It should be noted though, that your trigger updates the `TimePicker.Value` property, and will not update the `active_end_date` property it is bound to.

Comment: Is it possible to set DataContext value from DataTrigger's setter?

Comment: @Rachel: It would be great if you can add some line of code to handle this problem. Not experienced enough to understand this directly :(

Answer (score 0):

The property `TimePicker.Value` can only be set to one value at a time: either to a binding pointing to `active_end_date` or to a static date time string of `"01-01-0001 PM 05:00:00"`. Setting it to a string in a trigger like you have won't work to update the bound value, because it replaces the binding instead of updating it.

What you need to do is bind the `IsChecked` property of your `DailyFreqGroupRadio` checkbox to something in your `DataContext`, and handle it's `PropertyChanged` event to set the `active_end_date` to the value you want.

This is actually better MVVM design, as your `ViewModel` should model your `View`, and business logic such as the default value for a property when a certain box is checked should exist in the `ViewModel`, not in the `View`.

For example,

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding daily_freq_checked}" ... />
<xctk:TimePicker Value="{Binding Path=active_end_date}" ... />
```

and in your code behind

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "daily_freq_checked" && daily_freq_checked)
    {
        active_end_date = "01-01-0001 PM 05:00:00";
    }
}
```

It should probably also be noted that your current XAML won't trigger the `DataTrigger` because according to the [Dependency Property Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing), a value set locally in the XAML will take precedence over a Triggered value in a Style, so your triggered value will never get applied.